EKS auto mode cloudformation
I'm trying to create a new EKS cluster in auto mode using cloudformation using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-eks-cluster.html. It all works well except the default nodepools which don't get created by default.
I tried to specify them using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-eks-cluster-computeconfig.html but the deploy fails with a non detailed exception.
I expect to be able to get the built in one's e.g. System
Any ideas?

Can you share the configs used?
